# Eager load nested relationships in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4, eager-loading

I have six models: Division, Region, Area, Branch, Mis and Policy. A division has many regions, a region has many areas, an area has many branches, a branch has many mises, a mis has one policy and a policy belongs to one mis. I want to eager load a policy with its mis, branch, area, region and division. When I try to do that, a policy is loaded with mis and branch, but the other relations are not getting loaded. Here are my models:

Division:

```
public function regions () {
    return $this->hasMany(Region::class);
}
public function areas () {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Area::class, Region::class);
}
```

Region:

```
public function division () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Division::class);
}
public function areas () {
    return $this->hasMany(Area::class);
}
public function branches () {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Branch::class, Area::class);
}
```

Area:

```
public function region () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
}
public function branches () {
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::class);
}
```

Branch:

```
public function area () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
}
public function mises () {
    return $this->hasMany(Mis::class);
}
```

Mis:

```
public function policy () {
    return $this->hasOne(Policy::class);
}
public function branch () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class);
}
```

Policy:

```
public function mis () {
    return $this->belongsTo(Mis::class);
}
```

This is how I'm trying to do the eager loading:

```
public function showPolicyReport () {
    $policies = Policy::with('mis.branch.area.region.division')->get();
    dd($policies);
}
```

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Actually, the relations are loaded properly. It's the `dd()` method which is not showing all the nested relations.